# Undefined sign_up method for Michael Hartl: Exercise 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am unable to move to the signup page after clicking "Sign Up Now" in home page. I have gone through stack-overflow but none of them solve the problem. Here are my codes:

**Routes.rb**

```
get "users/new"
root :to => 'static_pages#home'

  match '/static_pages/home', :to => 'static_pages#home'
  match '/static_pages/help', :to => 'static_pages#help'
  match '/static_pages/about', :to => 'static_pages#about'
  match '/static_pages/contact', :to => 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/users/new', :to => 'users#new'
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", "signup_path", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

**header.html.erb**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", 'home' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", 'help' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", 'new' %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

I am stuck on this for long and unable to find the solution for this.

Comment: Can you post your controller actions as well.

Comment: try resources :users and then  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Try adding this to your routes.rb

```
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
```

Comment: cyborg/pavan - I couldn't add the comment as it requires 50 reputations to comment. I have edited my answer after seeing controller comment.

Comment: this is the solution which is present in stack-overflow and I have tried it but doesn't work for me. I have tried almost every possible solution

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would like to use

```
match '/users/new', :to => 'users#new'
```

as the `signup` route. You could specify this with the `:as` parameter like this:

```
match '/users/new', :to => 'users#new', :as => 'signup'
```

which will give you the correct `signup_path`.

Note that per the [Rails routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) you should now use `get` or `post` instead of `match` or specify `:via => [:post]` to disallow additional query parameters. Btw: your `signup` should be a `:post` as it attempts to change the state of the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
```

This worked fine for me and I don't know how I missed that